# how insert sys_categories with extbase

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

in a extbase extension i us sys_category. In list action there is no problem, all categories work as expected. But i want to write category entries with a custom database finisher from tx_form.

In the model all seems correct:

```
/**
 * Sets the categories
 *
 * @param  \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $categories
 * @return void
 */
public function setCategories($categories)
{
    $this->categories = $categories;
}
```

in my finisher:

```
$newAddress->setCategories($newCat);
$this->addressRepository->add($newAddress);
```

The form gives me only the uid of the category but for "setCategories" i need an \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage.

How do i get a \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage from the uid of the category?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a setter method for the categories like this:

```
public function addCategory($category)
{
    $this->categories->attach($category);
}
```

This method will add one model to your object storage.

As you need the category model to be added, you need to get the corresponding model of the `uid` with `$categoryRepository->findByUid($uid);`

Comment: do not forget that after the $newAddress->addCategory($newCat); you do not need the  $newAddress->setCategories($newCat); Just update the object via $this->addressRepository->add($newAddress); Otherwise it brings back an error